# android: How to use UI thread in service

Tags: android, rest, service

I have a service which is launched form a broadcast receiver, now in my service I want an API (Internal class API `PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone()`) to be called, but the API which I want to call is need to be called only from UI thread. how can I access UI thread from my service.

I tried ASYNC task but it did not work because the ASYC task need to be instanced from UI thread, since mine is service when I call the API it says need to be called from Looper Thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Handler` based on the thread executing `onCreate`, it will be the main (UI) thread. Then post a callback to that `Handler` with the API call in question.

Comment: can u just give me sample example if u dont mine. please

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Broadcast sent by your service and received by the Activity, and then do whatever you need with your UI.